# How to tune the spark executor number?

Tags: apache-spark

I submit a spark stream calculation task to my stand alone spark cluster. The submit command is like below:

```
./bin/spark-submit   \
--master spark://ES01:7077 \
--executor-memory 4G --num-executors 1\ 
/opt/flowSpark/sparkStream/latest5min.py    1>a.log 2>b.log
```

Note that I use num-executors 1. Because I only want one executor.

Then with ps comand I can find below output.

```
[root@ES01 ~]# ps -ef | grep java | grep -v grep  | grep spark
root     11659     1  0 Apr19 ?        00:48:25 java -cp /opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/conf/:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop/ -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip ES01 --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
root     11759     1  0 Apr19 ?        00:42:59 java -cp /opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/conf/:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop/ -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://ES01:7077
root     18538 28335 38 16:13 pts/1    00:01:52 java -cp /opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/conf/:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop/ -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --master spark://ES01:7077 --executor-memory 4G --num-executors 1 /opt/flowSpark/sparkStream/latest5min.py
root     18677 11759 46 16:13 ?        00:02:14 java -cp /opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/conf/:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop/ -Xms4096M -Xmx4096M -Dspark.driver.port=55652 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.79.148.184:55652 --executor-id 0 --hostname 10.79.148.184 --cores 1 --app-id app-20160509161303-0048 --worker-url spark://Worker@10.79.148.184:35012
root     18679 11759 46 16:13 ?        00:02:13 java -cp /opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/conf/:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop/ -Xms4096M -Xmx4096M -Dspark.driver.port=55652 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.79.148.184:55652 --executor-id 1 --hostname 10.79.148.184 --cores 1 --app-id app-20160509161303-0048 --worker-url spark://Worker@10.79.148.184:35012
root     18723 11759 47 16:13 ?        00:02:14 java -cp /opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/conf/:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop/ -Xms4096M -Xmx4096M -Dspark.driver.port=55652 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.79.148.184:55652 --executor-id 2 --hostname 10.79.148.184 --cores 1 --app-id app-20160509161303-0048 --worker-url spark://Worker@10.79.148.184:35012
```

From my understanding

11659 and 11759 is spark stand cluster process.

18538 is the driver program.

18677 18679 18723 should be worker process now.

Why there are still 3 since I already use the num-executor 1 ?

Comment: It doesn't look like three different executors, as they all share the same spark executor port, which would clash I think. Seems weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check spark.executor.cores in your spark defaults, from the documentation

```
The number of cores to use on each executor. For YARN and standalone mode only. 
In standalone mode, setting this parameter allows an application to run multiple executors on the same worker, provided that there are enough cores on that worker. 
Otherwise, only one executor per application will run on each worker.
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you are using YARN , you can check the executor by issuing below command in the datanode ( where executors will be instantiated)

```
 $ sudo -u yarn jps
 11388 CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend
 1854 Jps
 11396 CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend
```

CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend refers one executor.